# How to write JSON file to read data on CosmoDB on your Azure subscription using NodeJs module

Tags: node.js, azure-cosmosdb, azure-iot-hub

I have NodeJs code that writes fields to cosmoDB that needs to be read on Azure subscription as Analytics. All these I created on Azure portal itself, I have the following code written in NodeJs module and yes I do know CosmoDB support JSON format for SQL API invoke data;

```
{"bindings":[{"type":"eventHubTrigger","name":"IoTHubMessages","direction":"in","eventHubName":"MyEventHub","connection":"eNstaHub_events_IOTHUB","cardinality":"many","dataType":"string","consumerGroup":"$Default"}],"Telemetry":[{"Interval":"00:00:10","MessageTemplate":"{\"temperature\":${temperature},\"temperature_unit\":\"${temperature_unit}\",\"humidity\":\"${humidity}\"}","MessageSchema":{"Name":"eNtsaStatics","Format":"JSON","Fields":{"temperature":"double","temperature_unit":"text","humidity":"integer"}}}],"disabled":false}
```

What exactly am I not parsing write on my JSON format file?, yes in order for SQL API to read have to load JSON file on my path as a saved file. My challenge is that I need all these fields be exposed as an Analytics on my Azure subscription. For now I have understood this way of doing it, there are other options as well like SQL database when doing this on Azure subscription.

Comment: You mean you want to load data from json file into cosmos db ?

Comment: Not really i want to find out if there is a way in Azure, where my Nodejs from azure function can integrate with cosmosDB for data be exposed on azure portal(Dashboard).